# How can I exit a function as soon as a certain condition is met (without checking it at every line)?

Tags: c, multithreading, return, exit, threadx

I am developing a multi-threaded application. One of the threads is dedicated to handling an alarm system, which plays a certain alarm (sequence of specific tones) according to the alarm case. There's also an option to mute the alarm, by raising a flag from another thread. Whenever an alarm is muted, I want my program to immediately stop the alarm and not go through all the sequence. Below is a toy example of how my code is structured:

```
static int mute = 0;
static int current_alarm = 0;

void play_alarm_2 (void)
{
play_g_tone();
sleep(30);
play_a_tone();
sleep(20);
. . .
} 

void play_alarm_1 (void)
{
play_c_tone();
sleep(10);
play_f_tone();
sleep(20);
. . .
} 

void set_mute_status (int mute_status)
{
mute = mute_status;
}
void set_current_alarm (int alarm)
{
current_alarm = alarm;
}

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
    switch(current_alarm)
        case 1:
            play_alarm_1();
        case 2:
            play_alarm_2();
        . . .
    }
}
```

Other threads set the alarm case and the muting option. Now for example, if the alarm thread is currently inside play_alarm_2 and is playing the g_tone, if the user suddenly mutes the alarm, I would like to exit the function play_alarm_2 (the g_tone can finish to play, it doesnt have to cut it short necessarly). A stupid way to do it would be to add an every other line:

```
void play_alarm_2 (void)
{
if (mute)
    return

play_g_tone();

if (mute)
    return

sleep(30);

if (mute)
    return

play_a_tone();

if (mute)
    return

sleep(20);
. . .
}
```

Which again looks a bit stupid but does it solves my problem. I could also set up a macro maybe for it. But my question is, is there a more proper way to do this? Probably there is a solution that includes introducing another thread, but I would avoid it If i can. If really there's no way to do this without another thread, what would be the proper way to implement this?

P.S: This code will go on an embedded system and I am using ThreadX.

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to use a "modulo" counter? Do you know how to use a `switch()`? Can you think how you might combine these three fundamental ideas to solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah I know how to use those things.. But I dont see how combining them can solve this problem, can you share some more insight on this please? @Fe2O3

Comment: Re, "A stupid way to do it would be..." I would call that, "simple." Not "stupid." Sometimes, simple is smart. Whether or not it's smart _for you_ is a matter of opinion, and _your_ opinion in that case is the one that matters most. The answer from Fe2O3 (below) effectively does the same as your "stupid" solution, but it's (A) more compact (some people say that's good), and it's (B) harder to read and understand (some people say that's bad.) Your call!

Comment: @SolomonSlow Then again, by being "simple", long tracts of plodding, repetitious code have their own hazards and drawbacks. Clever use of iteration and modulo progression was exploited by Ravel to write his most famous work, "Bolero". (It has been claimed that that piece is still being played somewhere on Earth 24/7/365.) Think of Bach! One can strive to write code like Mozart wrote music... or like Salieri wrote his stuff... Beethoven: Da-Da-Da-Dummm Da-Da-Da-Dummm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch of "how to do this":

```
#define N 6 // 0-5 steps
for( int i = 0; ; i = (i+1) % N ) { // 0-1-2-3-4-5-0-1-2...
    switch( i ) {
        case 0: play_a_tone(); break;
        case 2: play_g_tone(); break;
        case 4: play_c_tone(); break;

        case 1:
        case 3:
            sleep(30);
            break;
        case 5:
            sleep(200);
            break;
    }
    if( mute ) return;
}
```

If the only thing happening in the function is this loop, you could even:

```
for( int i = 0; !mute; i = (i+1) % N ) {
```

and wouldn't need the extra `if()` at the bottom of the loop...

---

**UPDATE:**
Happened across this and wanted to post an 'improvement' that clearly separates the data from the functionality:

```
struct {
    void (*tone)();
    int dur;
} sqnc[] = {
    { play_a_tone,  30 }, // repeatedly played in sequence
    { play_g_tone,  30 },
    { play_c_tone, 200 },
    { play_f_tone,  30 },
};
const int N = sizeof sqnc/sizeof *sqnc;

for( int i = 0; !mute; i = (i+1) % N ) {
    sqnc[i].tone(); if( !mute ) sleep( sqnc[i].dur );
}
```

This suggests it could be made even simpler if the separate `play_X_tone()` functions were combined into a single function that takes and uses a parameter. Haven't seen that code, so this is just an observation.

(Just put Donna Summer's "I Feel Love" on the stereo... Multiple threads?? You're on your way to re-inventing the 'digital sequencer'. `:-)`)